# Sum 3 columns in row for a total column - MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a database which has many columns, but 3 of them I need to sum up. a, b & c .... I need to add a total column for every row (40+ rows) so each time a new score is entered into a,b or c ... the total column is updated for that particular row.

At the moment, I have the following Update that runs to enter a new score.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE national_reqs SET " . $phase . " = '" .$score . "' WHERE dog_name ='" . $dog_name . "'");
```

Then when I pull the data back out, I use the following query (and I want to sort by a new "Total" column)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT regfor,cat_num, ipolevel,handler,dog_name,a,b,c,score_time FROM 2015_national_reqs WHERE (id<=190) ORDER BY cat_num ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

I think I need a trigger to make this work properly ? I can create a new column for "Total" of type int.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

```
update [table] SET a = [value], d = (a+b+c) where id = [id];
```

Cheers